# Mostrar contenido de acuerdo a la versión del dispositivo android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy desarrollando una app la cual tiene como requerimiento funcional que pueda ser capas de funcionar en dispositivos con una versión del api 15, ahora bien la aplicación en las pruebas que e realizado funciona hasta cierto punto, hay componentes visuales que son compatibles con una versión del api 22 en adelante, e descargado los componentes compatibles con las versiones 15 pero no se como hacer para que al momento de detectar una versión inferior al api 22 me muestre algo o si es mayor o igual me muestre otro, ¿Como puedo hacer eso, que al momento de detectar una version inferior al api 22 me muestre algo compatible con esa version?, yas los componentes visuales los tengo creados para las diferentes versiones

Comment: Si te refieres a componentes de la interfaz grafica te recomiendo leer este enlace: https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html?hl=es-419 es algo trivial responder a tu pregunta ya que es muy generalizada

Comment: probaste usando supportLibraries?? los AppCompat[Componente] (por ej. AppCompatEditText) están para eso...